# Login users into their subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I've made authorization following this tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#cha-sign_in_sign_out. I've also added subdomain to `routes.rb` like this

```
match '/' => 'students/board', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'student' }
```

My user model holds a column which represents is user a student or not. I am not using any additional plugins for authorization and I don't want to :)

SessionHelper.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end
  .
  .
  .
  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                  User.digest(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      if(user.student)
          redirect_to root_url(:subdomain => 'student')
      else
          redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

When student tries to login he is logged in successfully and he is redirected to his subdomain. The problem is he is signed in only on the main site `site.com`, not on the subdomain `student.site.com`. After he is signed in and redirected to subdomain, he needs to sign in again. I want him to be signed in only in his domain `student.site.com` and not on main site.

What would be the best way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: check this so post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092893/rails-3-2-8-share-devise-sessions-across-subdomains-with-pow

Comment: @emcanes, thanks but I don't want to share sessions across all subdomains.