# Can't login with devise on heroku, all other environments work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I got an app that runs fine locally and on production (deployed with capistrano) and I'm trying to set up a staging environment which worked so far except for devise.

When I try to log in with working user credentials I get redirected to the root path but not logged in.

Logs:

```
Started POST "/login" for 95.91.228.167 at 2016-01-31 13:33:51 +0000
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2.7ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iHo8UfHuZ9S6GVbj3hAvfzqwo67FfZwZtdhwJ2qTk3Q=", "user"=>{"email"=>"xxx@xxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Einloggen"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Redirected to http://xxx.herokuapp.com/
Completed 302 Found in 81.5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 95.91.228.167 at 2016-01-31 13:33:51 +0000
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
```

I tried all solutions posted here like changing the domain in `session_store` and I updated devise to the most recent version.

Any ideas? If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` that's the error - have you tried clearing the cache of your browser?

Comment: Yes, I did but no success.

Comment: Seems like users is getting redirected to subdomain and session is not shared between subdomain. You can do it by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092893/rails-3-2-8-share-devise-sessions-across-subdomains-with-pow

Comment: I already set `domain: :all` but will give it a try by changing it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out `session_store.rb` had `domain: :all` which I thought was fine. Once I changed it to `xxx.herokuapp.com`, it worked. Thanks!

**--- Update 1 ---**

Now that it works on heroku, it doesn't work on the production server anymore - obviously because of the wrong URL in session_store. What to do now?

**--- Update 2 ---**

Solved this by using environment variables

Comment: Just change domain from `xxx.herokuapp.com` to `.herokuapp.com` or make it environmental variable

Comment: `.herokuapp.com` also doesn't work because it will break production environment which is not hosted on heroku. However, environmental variables are the way to go I think - thanks!